# Как с помошью MutationObserver отследить появления 2-х элементов на странице и один из них скрыть?

Tags: javascript

В оределённый момент на странице может появиться элементы `<div> id=a >` и `<div class=b >` Как скрыть `id=a` при обнаружении этих двух элементов на странице одновременно. А если обнаруживается один из них, то ни каких действий не придпринимать.
У меня есть рабочий код, который при обнаружении `id=a` скрывает  его. Что нужно внего добавить, что-бы получилось то что мне нодо?

```
new MutationObserver( Mutations => {
  for (let Mutation of Mutations) {
    for (let Node of Mutation.addedNodes) if (Node instanceof HTMLElement) {
      if (Node.matches('#a')) Node.style.display = "none";
      else {
        let El = Node.querySelector('#a');
        if (El) El.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}).observe( document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как скрыть id=a при обнаружении этих двух элементов на странице одновременно. А если обнаруживается один из них, то ни каких действий не придпринимать. У меня есть рабочий код, который при обнаружении id=a скрывает его. Что нужно внего добавить, что-бы получилось то что мне нодо?

Предложу такой вариант решения с использованием твоего кода...

```js
com.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const t = e.target.dataset.e
  if (!t) return
  if (t === 'clear') {
    box.innerHTML = ''
    return
  }
  if (t === 'all') {
    box.innerHTML = ''
    const o = document.createElement('div')
    const a = create('a')
    const b = create('b')
    o.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', a)
    o.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', b)
    box.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', o)
    return
  }
  const o = create(t)
  box.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', o)
  //
  function create(id) {
    const o = document.createElement('p')
    o.id = id
    o.textContent = id
    return o
  }
})
new MutationObserver( Mutations => {
  const a = find('#a')
  const b = find('#b')
  if (a && b) a.style.display = "none"
  //
  function find(t) {
    for (let Mutation of Mutations) {
      for (let Node of Mutation.addedNodes) if (Node instanceof HTMLElement) {
        if (Node.matches(t)) return Node;
        else {
          let El = Node.querySelector(t);
          if (El) return El;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}).observe( document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

```html
<section id=com>
  <button data-e='a'>Добавить А</button>
  <button data-e='b'>Добавить Б</button>
  <button data-e='all'>Добавить А и Б</button>
  <button data-e='clear'>Очистить</button>
</section>
<section id='box'></section>
```

Comment: видимо я плохо сформулировал вопрос. Попробую уточнить. Вот то код, который я дал он уже почти что нужно, но в него нужно что-то добавить, чтобы скрывался id=a, т.е применялся `display = "none";` если на странице одновременно появились `<div> id=a > и <div class=b >`

Comment: @User, т.е. нужно именно "одновременное появление"?

Comment: "ksa Да,  когда на странице имеется `id=a` и `class=b`.  то  `id =a` автоматически должнен скрыться. Если только один из перечисленных элементов, то ничего не должно скрываться.

Comment: @User, я изменил пример... Он теперь учитывает одновременное появление элементов.

Comment: ksa а в тот код который я дал нельзя внести изменения? Он бы сразу мне подошёл.

Comment: @User, так я так и сделал... Оформил поиск элемента функцией и ее потом использовал. Тебе лишь нужно указать свои селекторы `#a` и `.b`...

Comment: понял, сейчас проверю

Comment: к сожалению код ну никак не хочет работать. Верно подставляю свои селекторы. Ну не работает и всё.

Comment: @User, значит что-то там еще у тебя не так. Я специально сделал полностью рабочий тестовый пример для демонстрации своего варианта.

Comment: код который ты мне дал работает идеально. Код у меня не хотел работать, потому-что селекторы #a и .b оказываеся были постоянно на странице и находились они в теге <script>

Comment: ksa,  как только я поменял условный #a на div[id="a"]' и .b на  div[class="b"]  в коде, всё сразу заработало как надо.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы скрыть элемент с id="a" только в случае, если на странице одновременно присутствуют оба элемента с id="a" и элементы с классом "b", вы можете модифицировать ваш код таким образом:

```
new MutationObserver(Mutations => {
  let hasIdA = false;
  let hasClassB = false;

  for (let Mutation of Mutations) {
    for (let Node of Mutation.addedNodes) {
      if (Node instanceof HTMLElement) {
        if (Node.matches('#a')) {
          hasIdA = true;
        } else if (Node.matches('.b')) {
          hasClassB = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Если есть и #a и .b, то скрываем #a
  if (hasIdA && hasClassB) {
    const elementA = document.querySelector('#a');
    if (elementA) {
      elementA.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}).observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Этот код вводит две переменные, hasIdA и hasClassB, которые отслеживают наличие элементов с id="a" и классом "b". Если оба элемента присутствуют одновременно, то элемент с id="a" скрывается. Если только один из них есть на странице, никаких действий не предпринимается.