# Как отследить появления элемента с помощью MutationObserver и удалить событие onclick?

Tags: javascript

Как отследить появление элемента используя наблюдатель или другие методы и удалить у него событие onclick `document.querySelector('div[class="button"]').removeAttribute('onclick');` ?

```
new MutationObserver( Mutations => {
  for (let Mutation of Mutations) {
    for (let Node of Mutation.addedNodes) if (Node instanceof HTMLElement) {
      if (Node.matches('.button')) Node.removeAttribute('onclick');
      else {
        let El = Node.querySelector('.button');
        if (El) El.removeAttribute('onclick');
      }
    }
  }
}).observe( document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Comment: Атрибут не есть событие... https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events

Comment: Вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1540604/Как-с-помошью-mutationobserver-отследить-появления-2-х-элементов-на-странице-и-о/1540618#comment2771849_1540618 я приводил пример "поиска элемента" в `MutationObserver`

Comment: ksa, в вопросе добавил код. Так у меня работает.  Ещё вопрос. А можно в этот код добавить своё событие onclick теперь? Если да, то как?

Comment: @ksa Данный пользователь уже который раз задает вопросы про MutationObserver)))

Comment: Получив ссылку на элемент - можно с ним делать все что угодно...